# Update a row after Select Into variable

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I am trying to update a row in a table after a SELECT INTO ROW. However I have not been successful and have not really found information on how to do this.

I have tried the below codes and they have not worked for me

This approach is not giving errors, but the output is definitely not what I expected

```sql
SELECT * 
    INTO row1
    FROM table1
    WHERE column1 = '1'
    AND column3 = '1'
    AND column4 = '1';

    row1.column2 := '2';

    UPDATE table1
    SET ROW = row1;
```

I also tried this approach and it throws errors

```sql
    SELECT *
    INTO row1
    FROM table1
    WHERE column1 = '1'
    AND column3 = '1'
    AND column4 = '1';


    UPDATE table1
    SET column2 = '2'
    WHERE VALUES row1;
```

Comment: It would help if you gave sample data, said what output you expected and got from the first attempt (and whether your update really has no `where` clause); and what errors you got from the second attempt. I can guess, but it's better to tell us what you actually see. All by [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57331684/edit). Why do you want to do it in two stages; and is column1 unique?

Comment: Great question, so basically this table doesn't have a primary key so the only way to find it is to compare it with several values in the row that I got from the SELECT INTO. I will edit it so I put several conditions in there, but yes, it will be a unique row with several conditions.

Comment: I know I can say

Comment: Please state your requirement clearly without using query syntax. From the samples you shared looks like you are trying to do `update table1 set column2='2' where column1='1' and column3='1' and column4='1'; `. If that is not the case then please explain what do you need.

Comment: Exactly that would be it, but since I already have the values in my row variable is there a way to skip the WHERE column1 = row1.column1 AND column3 = row1.column3 .... columnN = row1.columnN?

Comment: For future reference *"it throws errors"* is no use to us. We don't have your schema or your data, so we can't run your code and see what the error is. Consequently we need you to tell us the exact error message you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious solution is to just add a `where` clause to the update, matching your query filter - assuming (as you said in comments) those together represent a unique row (the `select into` would fail otherwise anyway, of course):

```
UPDATE table1
SET ROW = row1
WHERE column1 = '1';
```

or

```
WHERE column1 = row1.column1;
```

If you really don't want to do that, you could use a cursor and [`for update`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/static-sql.html#GUID-6A1C2FD9-9476-4F8D-A2E4-2C967D7F8C08) and [`where current of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/UPDATE-statement-extensions.html), which has the advantage of locking the row (although you can do that with the previous version too):

```
declare
  row1 table1%rowtype;
  cursor c is
    select * from table1 where column1 = '1'
    for update;
begin
  open c;
  fetch c into row1;

  row1.column2 := '2';

  update table1
  set row = row1
  where current of c;

  close c;
end;
/
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3a7b53df384d1d8f7d539b2e92f9ffb0)

If you are actually updating multiple rows in a loop anyway then you can just use that cursor and fetch inside a loop. You might then want to look into `bulk collect` and `forall` instead, applying your transformations to each element of the collection. That doesn't seem to be part of the question, but added just in case your real situation is more complicated.

Of course, this assumes you have a legitimate reason for doing the `select` and `update` as two stages, instead of a simple update to set the new column value directly:

```
UPDATE table1
SET column2 = '2'
WHERE column1 = '1';
```

... which can be in a PL/SQL block but doesn't need to be.

Also, if your columns are numbers you should compare them with numbers; `= '1'` looks suspicious.